# Obtaining original variable name from within an extension method

Tags: c#, reflection, extension-methods

We are currently working on a logging solution and have implemented an extension method call 'Log'. When writing to the log file, we would ideally like to write the original variable name (rather than the variable name used in the extension method).

What we are currently having to do for this is:

```
public void DoSomeWork()
{
    String testString = "Hey look I'm a string!";
    testString.Log("testString value");
}
```

With the extention method:

```
public static String Log(this String valueToStore, String name)
{
    // The logging code which uses the 'name' parameter
}
```

The issue here is that it becomes difficult to read on longer lines of code and looks clustered. What would be ideal is this:

```
public void DoSomeWork()
{
    String testString = "Hey look I'm a string!";
    testString.Log();
}
```

With the extension method:

```
public static String Log(this String valueToStore)
{
    // The logging code which is able to retrieve the 
    // value 'testString' from the 'valueToStore' value
}
```

Is this at all possible by using Reflection? I'm aware of the `nameof`option, but that only returns the string 'valueToStore' when used in the extension method.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. This information is lost at this point of execution (a variable is not even a property or field you could reflect on). You can walk up the stack frame and examine the calling method for its string variables, but that won't help. btw: what would you expect from `"hello world".Log()`?

Comment: Does an extension method not need to remain linked to where it was called from? I get that this wouldn't be possible using a regular method but thought extension methods may offer something a bit extra

Comment: No, extension methods are just syntactic sugar. `testString.Log()` in your example is not different from `YourExtensionClass.Log(testString)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `Expression` to achieve that, but performance-wise it may not be the best option:

```
public static void Log<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
{
    var memberExpr = expr.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (memberExpr == null)
        return;

    var varName = memberExpr.Member.Name;
    var varData = expr.Compile()();

    // actual logging
    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
var test = "Foo";
Log(() => test);
```

Alternatively, if you're using C# 6.0, it can get a bit better using the `nameof` operator:

```
test.Log(nameof(test));
```

A better solution would be one that is leveraging the compiler abilities (specifically, the "Roslyn" compiler) and provide the member name on compile time.

Comment: How would the usage be implemented as an extension method, or would this solution be moving away from that?

Comment: @ChrisWright, You can extend it to be an extension method, but it'll look pretty awkward: `test.Log(() => test)`. I can modify the answer to reflect that if you wish.

Comment: It should be ok, I pasted it in as just a standard method and made the call to see it working so I can probably convert it from there. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @ChrisWright, I made a slight change to the code to accommodate logging of non-string types as well.

Answer (score 4):

Well, short answer is no. The variable names are not guaranteed to persist after compilation in unchanged form. That information would have to be somehow persisted (for example by the use of `nameof()`). Also, the variable name might not exist (`"test".GetVarName()`).

The long answer is: yes, possibly, but it's one of the most ridiculous things I've created in my life:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Test1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myVarName = "test";
            myVarName.Test();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    static class Extensions
    {
        public static void Test(
            this string str,
            [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
            [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
            [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0
        )
        {
            var relevantLine = File.ReadAllLines(sourceFilePath)[sourceLineNumber-1];
            var currMethodName = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
            var callIndex = relevantLine.IndexOf(currMethodName + "()");
            var sb = new Stack<char>();

            for (var i = callIndex - 2; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(relevantLine[i]))
                {
                    sb.Push(relevantLine[i]);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(new String(sb.ToArray()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

C# 10 has [CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerargumentexpressionattribute?view=net-6.0) that will do just that

```
public static void PrintNameAndValue(
    this object obj,
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerArgumentExpression("obj")] string callerExp = ""
    )
{
    Console.WriteLine(callerExp + " = " + obj.ToString());
}
```

It'll capture the entire expression passed:

```
public void TestPrintNameAndValue()
{
    string mystring = "test";
    int myint = 5;

    mystring.PrintNameAndValue();             // mystring = test
    myint.PrintNameAndValue();                // myint = 5
    (myint + 10).PrintNameAndValue();         // myint + 10 = 15
    mystring.ToUpper().PrintNameAndValue();   // mystring.ToUpper() = TEST
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, more of a pointer, but you could try doing something with your application that you're using(e.g. visual studio) instead of doing it in code. What I mean is make it rewrite everything that looks like `[variable].Log();` to `[variable].Log([variable])`

I am pretty sure that there has to be some weird macro or plugin which does this for you before compiling.